# Access denied in flyway on deploy to the heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, flyway

When attempting to deploy, even with certain password and user, flyway is not allowed to migrate. Can someone help me? follows log error below.

> 2018-12-10 02:07:55.578 ERROR 4 --- [           main]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
>   connections of pool. 2018-12-10T02:07:55.579896+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.579898+00:00 app[web.1]: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user ''@'ec2-54-91-197-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
>   (using password: YES) 2018-12-10T02:07:55.579899+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.579901+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.579903+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]

---

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.611900+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to obtain
>   connection from database: Access denied for user
>   ''@'ec2-54-91-197-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.611902+00:00 app[web.1]:

---

> 2018-12-10T02:07:55.611904+00:00 app[web.1]: SQL State  : 28000
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.611906+00:00 app[web.1]: Error Code : 1045
>   2018-12-10T02:07:55.611908+00:00 app[web.1]: Message    : Access
>   denied for user ''@'ec2-54-91-197-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using
>   password: YES) 2018-12-10T02:07:55.611909+00:00 app[web.1]:

Comment: this message looks funky `' user ''@'ec2-54-91-197-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com' `. Did you use the correct database credentials?

Comment: Are you using the JDBC_DATABASE_URL provided by Heroku?

Comment: yes, as credentials are correct, yet it still denies access when you start the application on Heroku, the credentials used were those provided by Heroku when installing MYSQL

Comment: [RESOLVED] - I noticed that the variables in the "application properties" file were in the wrong nomenclature for the JAWSDB